# VBA finds workbook, then gives an error saying it is missing

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using some code in VBA to open a workbook from a directory:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFile As String
Dim src As Workbook
Dim books As Object

Set today = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set books = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\userA\Documents\XXX\scripts" & "\*" & ".xlsm")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    MsgBox (StrFile)
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(StrFile, True, True)
    Call createInput
    src.Close SaveChanges:=False

    StrFile = Dir

Loop
```

Now this will find my workbook and print out the name in a MsgBox, but then when the below line is called, I get a Runtime 1004 error (not found, "Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

```
Set src = Workbooks.Open(StrFile, True, True)
```

I don't understand how this is possible, as it is clearly demonstrating that the file exists. Can anyone guide me as to where I'm going wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what createInput does but shouldn't you be passing src into it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the path. Dir only returns the filename so unless "C:\Users\userA\Documents\XXX\scripts\" just happened to be the default path, the workbook will appear missing.

```
dim fp as string
fp = "C:\Users\userA\Documents\XXX\scripts\"

StrFile = Dir(fp & "*.xlsm")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    MsgBox (StrFile)
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(fp & StrFile, True, True)
    Call createInput
    src.Close SaveChanges:=False

    StrFile = Dir

Loop
```

You might want to look into using `environ("USERPROFILE")` to construct the string containing your path. e.g.:

```
fp = environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\XXX\scripts\"
```